# Closest match for job titles

Tags: java, nlp, extract, data-analysis, summarization

I have master list of known job titles and looking for ways to extract the same from the searched term. For example:

Searched job title: **Senior Digital Marketing Specialist**
Extracted to: **Senior Digital Marketing**

Searched job title: **Retail In-Store Sales Assistant; Full Time**
Extracted to: **Retail Sales Assistant**

So I tried to extract parameters that would be helpful for cleaning up the searched query. 
1) The occurrence of the 2 tokens in the db. (To get mathematical evaluation of how much are the terms related with each other)
Example:

```
 t01->t0 or t1        Senior || java--->226374 
 t02->t0 or t2        Senior || software--->2566450 
 t03->t0 or t3        Senior || engineer--->7220787 
 t12->t1 or t2        java || software--->315397
 t13->t1 or t3        java || engineer--->407682
 t23->t2 or t3        software || engineer--->11533495

 total =t01+t02+t03+t12+t13+t23
```

[image]

2) The occurrence of the token taken 1 at time in the entire db.
Example:

```
t0->    Senior----->55042636  
t1->    java----->1655805
t2->    software----->26136204
t3->    engineer----->81574912
```

3) I took the sum of the related tokens and put a minimum threshold of 5% and that give me the following output, i.e (txy*100)/total > 5

My Output : **Senior software engineer**
Anyone have any experience with similar projects or ideas for further improvement ?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. Do you assume that the query is always a superset of some entry in your master list?

Comment: @Thomas No it may not be a superset at all. 
Example: Searched job title: Full Time Java Developer in New York 
Extracted to: Java Developer

In the database I have none of the job title would contain the term "New York" , hence they are easily removed.

Comment: Have you considered using some kind of a full text search engine like lucene or elasticsearch? It might be better than the database

Comment: @bedrin Thanks for the suggestion. We will try it out.

Comment: I still don't get it. To me "Full Time Java Developer in New York" *is* a superset of "Java Developer". Perhaps my notion of "set" was not clear, I was thinking of a sets whose elements are the different words of the query or data base entries.

Comment: How did you finally solve it?

Answer (score 1):

One standard approach to determine similarity between a query and your list entries would be a [vector space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model). Roughly speaking, you could go about building such a model with the following steps:

1. Defining the dimensionality of your vector space **(offline)**

```
term-list = []
for-all job titles in your master list:
    for-all words in the current job-title:
        canonicalize(current-word)  // e.g. to-lower-case, etc.
        if not contains(term-list, current-word):
            add(current-word, term-list)
sort(term-list)
n = size(term-list)
```

The length `n` of the `term-list` is the size of your vector space.

2. Associate each job title from the master list with a vector **(offline)**

```
vector-list = []
vector = []
fill(vector, 0, n-1, 0) // initialize to n zeros
for-all job titles in your master list:
    for-all words in the current job-title:
        canonicalize(current-word)  // e.g. to-lower-case, etc.
        term-index = index-of(current-word, term-list)
        vector[term-index]++
normalize(vector) // scale vector to length = 1
add(vector, vector-list)
```

3. Transform each search `query` into a vector as well **(online)**

This works exactly like the code under 2., except that you only have one for-loop (the inner one) in which you iterate over the words in the query instead of the words of a master-list job title. Also, you don't need a `vector-list` for obvious reasons.

The result is a normalized `query-vector`.

4. Measure the relevance of a job-title given a `query-vector` using cosine similarity **(online)**

```
similarities-vector = []
for-all job-title vectors in vector-list:
    similarity = dotProduct(query-vector, job-title-vector)
    add(similarity, similarities-vector)
```

The result is a similarity value between the query and each entry of your master-list, stored in the `similarities-vector`.

This is a very general model, and its appeal lies in its simplicity. However, it's debatable whether it's a very good model for the job at hand, given that your job titles will typically consist of only a small number of words that probably only appear once in each job title. But you may give it a try.

Comment: After a few trials I found Lucene suited me for the results I was looking for. It internally uses vector space model, so I found it easier to use it rather to code it myself.

Comment: Would like more suggestions on this. There could be another suggestion in terms of approach for this problem :)